# upgrade ubuntu 12.04 to 13

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I am having trouble upgrading   to the latest version of ubuntu. I have checked the application manager and it will not show the upgrade. Should
I just download the latest version and install it rather than trying to upgrade. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It will not show the upgrade, because you probably have set to only notify on upgrades of new LTS releases. This would be 14.04 released next year. If you want to upgrade to a regular non-LTS release like 13.04 is, then you should change that setting.

[image]

The command-line way of changing this is as follows:

1. Open `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` in your favourite text editor, e.g.:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
   ```
2. Change the line

   ```
   prompt=lts
   ```

   to

   ```
   prompt=normal
   ```
3. Save and close.
4. Run the regular upgrade procedure:

   ```
   sudo do-release-upgrade
   ```

Answer (score 2):

go to `system settings` -> `software & Updates`, and under the tab `Updates` make sure that at 'notify me of a new Ubuntu version' is set to `For any nev version` if you want to upgrade from 12.04 to 13.04 you will first need to upgrade to 12.10 and to 13.04 from there. this made me decide to just download the new iso and install it that way (wich is very easy if you have a seporate /home partition...)

Answer (score 1):

did you checked in to: System Settings - Software & Updates - Updates (the tab), down there it's a dropdown menu - Notify me of a new Ubuntu version - (select from the menu) For eny new version
Do restart or log out, and then check again for updates.